# How do I change the order of sections in a Wordpress template?

Tags: php, wordpress

This may be a dumb question, but I would like to change the Wordpress template below so that the "<**div id="primary" class="content-area"**>" section comes AFTER the "<**div id="secondary**>". Would I just simply change the order of these? I have not tried to change it as I don't want to mess up the website.

```
<?php
/**
    * The Template for displaying all single posts.
    *
    * @package vantage
    * @since vantage 1.0
    * @license GPL 2.0
    */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $job_title = get_field('job_title');
    $phone = get_field('phone');
    $cell_phone = get_field('cell_phone');
    $fax = get_field('fax');
    $client_email_alt = get_field('email');
    $linkedin_link = get_field('linkedin_link');
    $profile_pdf = get_field('profile_pdf');
    $p_area = get_field('practice_area');
    $v_card = get_field('vcard_vcf');

    $representative_matters = "representative_matters";
    $rep_label = get_field_object($representative_matters);

    ?>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php echo $location ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <div id="addl-info">
                <!--<?php if ( $representative_matters['value'] ) {
                    echo '<div class="block"><h3>' .$rep_label['label']. '</h3>' .$rep_label['value']. '</div>';
                } ?>-->

                <?php

                    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                    if( have_rows('additional_content') ):
                        // loop through the rows of data
                        while ( have_rows('additional_content') ) : the_row();

                            // display a sub field value
                            echo '<div class="block"><h3>';
                            the_sub_field('box_title');
                            echo '</h3>';
                            the_sub_field('box_content');
                            echo '</div>';

                        endwhile;
                    else :
                        // no rows found
                    endif;

                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ( siteorigin_setting( 'navigation_post_nav' ) ) vantage_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : ?>
            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
</div><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<div id="secondary">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
          <img class="profile-pic" src="<?php
            $loadthumb = simplexml_load_string(get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'full'));
            $thumbsrc = $loadthumb->attributes()->src;
            echo $thumbsrc;
          ?>">
    <?php } else { ?>
            <img src="<?=site_url('/wp-content/uploads/no-pic.jpg'); ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <ul class="profile-info">
        <li class="name"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <?php if ( $job_title['value'] ) { echo '<li>'.$job_title.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $phone['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$phone.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $cell_phone['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$cell_phone.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $fax['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-fax" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$fax.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $client_email['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="mailto:'.$client_email.'">'.$client_email.'</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $client_email_alt['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="mailto:'.$client_email_alt.'">'.$client_email_alt.'</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $linkedin_link['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="'.$linkedin_link.'" target="_blank">linkedin Profile</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $profile_pdf['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';} ?>
        <?php if ( $profile_pdf['value'] ) { echo '<a href="'.$profile_pdf.'" target="_blank">Download Profile</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $v_card['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>';} ?>
        <?php if ( $v_card['value'] ) { echo '<a href="'.$v_card.'" target="_blank">Get Vcard</a></li>'; } ?>
    </ul>

    <?php if( $p_area ): ?>
    <h3 class="sub-title">Practice Areas</h3>
    <ul class="practice-area">
        <?php foreach( $p_area as $area ): ?>
            <li><?php
            $area_class = $area;
            $area_class = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $area_class);
            $file_path = site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/'.$area_class.'.pdf';
            if (get_headers($file_path)[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {
                echo '<a href="'.$file_path.'" target="_blank">';
                echo $area;
                echo '</a>';
            } else {
                echo $area;
            }
            ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('awards') ):
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('awards') ) : the_row();

            // display a sub field value
            echo '<li class="award"><img src="';
            the_sub_field('award');
            echo '"></li>';

        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;

    ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have not tried to edit anything yet. This is a template on a live Wordpress website which displays the bios of each of the company's representatives.

****Update - I tested it as recommended by others in the comments and it changed the order correctly but now all of the info under the secondary section, specifically the info under <**ul class="profile-info"**>, is not showing up. Here is how it looks now:

```
<?php
/**
    * The Template for displaying all single posts.
    *
    * @package vantage
    * @since vantage 1.0
    * @license GPL 2.0
    */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="secondary">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
          <img class="profile-pic" src="<?php
            $loadthumb = simplexml_load_string(get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'full'));
            $thumbsrc = $loadthumb->attributes()->src;
            echo $thumbsrc;
          ?>">
    <?php } else { ?>
            <img src="<?=site_url('/wp-content/uploads/no-pic.jpg'); ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <ul class="profile-info">
        <li class="name"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <?php if ( $job_title['value'] ) { echo '<li>'.$job_title.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $phone['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$phone.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $cell_phone['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$cell_phone.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $fax['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-fax" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$fax.'</li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $client_email['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="mailto:'.$client_email.'">'.$client_email.'</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $client_email_alt['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="mailto:'.$client_email_alt.'">'.$client_email_alt.'</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $linkedin_link['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="'.$linkedin_link.'" target="_blank">linkedin Profile</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $profile_pdf['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';} ?>
        <?php if ( $profile_pdf['value'] ) { echo '<a href="'.$profile_pdf.'" target="_blank">Download Profile</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php if ( $v_card['value'] ) { echo '<li><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>';} ?>
        <?php if ( $v_card['value'] ) { echo '<a href="'.$v_card.'" target="_blank">Get Vcard</a></li>'; } ?>
    </ul>

    <?php if( $p_area ): ?>
    <h3 class="sub-title">Practice Areas</h3>
    <ul class="practice-area">
        <?php foreach( $p_area as $area ): ?>
            <li><?php
            $area_class = $area;
            $area_class = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $area_class);
            $file_path = site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/'.$area_class.'.pdf';
            if (get_headers($file_path)[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {
                echo '<a href="'.$file_path.'" target="_blank">';
                echo $area;
                echo '</a>';
            } else {
                echo $area;
            }
            ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('awards') ):
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('awards') ) : the_row();

            // display a sub field value
            echo '<li class="award"><img src="';
            the_sub_field('award');
            echo '"></li>';

        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;

    ?>
</div>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $job_title = get_field('job_title');
    $phone = get_field('phone');
    $cell_phone = get_field('cell_phone');
    $fax = get_field('fax');
    $client_email_alt = get_field('email');
    $linkedin_link = get_field('linkedin_link');
    $profile_pdf = get_field('profile_pdf');
    $p_area = get_field('practice_area');
    $v_card = get_field('vcard_vcf');

    $representative_matters = "representative_matters";
    $rep_label = get_field_object($representative_matters);

    ?>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php echo $location ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <div id="addl-info">
                <!--<?php if ( $representative_matters['value'] ) {
                    echo '<div class="block"><h3>' .$rep_label['label']. '</h3>' .$rep_label['value']. '</div>';
                } ?>-->

                <?php

                    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                    if( have_rows('additional_content') ):
                        // loop through the rows of data
                        while ( have_rows('additional_content') ) : the_row();

                            // display a sub field value
                            echo '<div class="block"><h3>';
                            the_sub_field('box_title');
                            echo '</h3>';
                            the_sub_field('box_content');
                            echo '</div>';

                        endwhile;
                    else :
                        // no rows found
                    endif;

                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ( siteorigin_setting( 'navigation_post_nav' ) ) vantage_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : ?>
            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
</div><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Don't you have a development or testing environment? That way you can experiment as much as you need to, to get it right. Professional developers don't mess about with their live systems either.

Comment: why not check it via the browser elements console? check them and see what effect happening. But agreed with @ADyson that when you are going to test it really via code change, then use a test environment. (create it locally by cloning or on the live server by creating a sub-domain and cloning the website over there).

Or at least have a backup of the above file and then you can change it directly too.

Comment: I tested it and it changed the order correctly but now all of the info under the secondary section is not showing up.

Comment: Your edit needs to show us precisely what you changed, so we can compare the two versions of the code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The part that gets all the database information needed for the "secondary" part and defines variables from it, which is now inside the code of the "primary" part, needs to remain *before*  the code of the "secondary" part since that second part uses the values from all these variables.

I mean this code:

```
<?php
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  $job_title = get_field('job_title');
  $phone = get_field('phone');
  $cell_phone = get_field('cell_phone');
  $fax = get_field('fax');
  $client_email_alt = get_field('email');
  $linkedin_link = get_field('linkedin_link');
  $profile_pdf = get_field('profile_pdf');
  $p_area = get_field('practice_area');
  $v_card = get_field('vcard_vcf');

  $representative_matters = "representative_matters";
  $rep_label = get_field_object($representative_matters);

?>
```

Move that a few lines up, up to to directly after `get_header()` and then change the order of the rest of the code.

Comment: Oh that would make sense..it's now displaying correctly. Thank you Johannes!!!